# Where can I ask how Google Weather gets all its data?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask the following question:

> How does Google Weather get all data like temperature and wind etc. Of every city. Do they collect data from satellites?

On which Stack Exchange site would this question be on-topic?

Comment: Seriously though, Google does almost nothing like that in-house. They just buy the same commercial weather data that local TV stations do, from different companies all over the world. They like to take credit for everybody else's hard work.

Comment: @AbhiChavda I don’t think anyone outside of Google would *know*. Even if you find an SE site to ask on, it may be that no one can give you an answer, or that you may not be able to trust any answers you get. Company internal processes are just that - internal.

Comment: I thought [the data is from weather.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd42q.png)? Anyway, the question was already asked on [Android.SE]: [Where does Google Now get its weather data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/45093)

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that there is SE site for your question.

[Web Applications](https://weapps.stackexchange.com) could be the closest site, as the question could be about a Google (web search), but the scope of this site is about using a web application, not about the data sources per se.

As pointed out on a comment, also a similar question could be on topic on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com) as there are several Android apps that return weather results.

Maybe you could make a related question like where to check the data source of an specific query / result as Google could use several data sources as they love to "personalize" results, i.e. they could use different data sources for different cities due to any criteria that they want to use, like relevance, user rating, costs, A/B testing, etc.

[Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) has a some way related questions:

- [From where do weather radar maps get their data?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/2959/14596)
- [What is the status of meteorological data exchange standards?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/2813/14596)

[Internet of Things](https://iot.stackexchange.com/) also has a some way related question:

- [How to ask Multiple questions to Google Home](https://iot.stackexchange.com/q/2147/34) (several of the sample questions are about weather)