# Where can I ask questions about weather and climate?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask questions about weather and climate? I wanted to ask this:

> If Central America was flooded, then what would happen to the Gulfstream, and thus the weather in Western Europe?

Answer (score 9):

Try https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/

From their [Tour page](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/tour)

> Earth Science Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences.

They have a tag for [weather-forecasting](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weather-forecasting) and other related tags.

Related

- [Where can I ask how Google Weather gets all its data?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320826/289691)